# Get the public path directory

Tags: 8, files

I want to save file programmatically in public path, and I want to know how can I get `Public Directory path` in Drupal 8. In Drupal 7, I would use the following code.

```
drupal_realpath(file_default_scheme() . '://')
```

What is the equivalent in Drupal 8?

Comment: Both functions actually still exist, drupal_realpath() is just deprecated. If a function is deprecated, you can almost always just look at its implementation as it then usually calls the new service/API. You can also always search the change records: https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/published?keywords_description=drupal_realpath&to_branch=&version=&created_op=%3E%3D&created%5Bvalue%5D=&created%5Bmin%5D=&created%5Bmax%5D=

Comment: Also, two related comments: 1. You're saving in the *default* path. That might be public but it might also be something else. You can just hardcode public:// if you always want it to be in public. 2. Most API's can handle public:// directly, e.g. any or almost any file* PHP functions like file_put_contents(). There is no reason to convert it yourself. In fact, some stream wrappers like e.g. an amazon S3 storage implementation will not even allow that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [realpath API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/8), you can get it with:

```
\Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(file_default_scheme() . '://');
```

Comment: You're missing the file_default_scheme() part, this doesn't do anything. But that still exists.

Comment: Added that in an edit.

Comment: when I do this I get the files-private directory.  How do I get the public directory

Comment: @Diana the code above should give you the public path. To get the private you can do this: \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath("private://");

Comment: @NickO your code doesn't works for me for the private filesystem path

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to get just "sites/default/files" or "sites/your-multisite/files"
Then you should use

```
// Add to the top of the file.
use Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PublicStream;

// In your method.
print PublicStream::basePath();
```

Comment: and `Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PrivateStream::basePath()` for private file path