# How can I get the URL to the public files directory?

Tags: 8, uri, files

I can get the *path* to the public files directory by using [`Filesystem::realpath`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!File!FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Arealpath/8.2.x):

```
$path = $filesystem->realpath('public://');
```

But how can I get the URL of `public://`?

Comment: Already answred.
[Get similar answer from here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185572/get-the-public-path-directory/)

Comment: @bhupendraosd I want the URL, and not the path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$my_path = file_create_url("public://");
```

Will definately work, however it's not coming from a service. Let me investigate more on this!

**Okey I found it!** [This](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/8.0.x) is how file_create_url works:

And this is the corresponding line specific to "public://" resolving (if you are sure you are trying to resolve a "public://..." uri):

```
  if ($wrapper = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getViaUri($uri)) {
  return $wrapper->getExternalUrl();
}
```

Which means you will have to use StreamWrapperManager service, and after calling the getViaUri, you will able to get the external url. So this is **service based solution**!

Comment: I looked at [Url::fromUri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x), but couldn't get it to work with `public://`. Ideally I would like to use a service.

Comment: `file_create_url` works fine.

Comment: Came back to this. `stream_wrapper_manager` works as intended!

Answer (score 2):

After Drupal 9.3.3, you can do this with the `field_url_generator` service.

```php
$url = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generate('public://basename.ext');
```

This returns a path to the file like `/sites/default/files/basename.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve it.

```
$wrapper = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getViaScheme(file_default_scheme());
return $wrapper::baseUrl();
```

will return DOMAIN/sites/default/files for my case.
For 'public', $wrapper belongs to class "PublicStream", you can check other methods inside.

I've added it because this works for me:

```
$my_path = file_create_url("public://");
```

But this not work:

```
if ($wrapper = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getViaUri($uri)) {
  return $wrapper->getExternalUrl();
}
```

in my project, it returns "public://".

Maybe it's related to update of Drupal Core or some settings. Unfortunately, it's not easy to find the root cause.
I hope this information will be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I was having -

```
public://2019-03/YxoEy6.png
```

and I got the image by -

```
<img class="item-logo" src="{{file_url(restricted_item.logo_name.logo )}}" alt="logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 9 and 10**

Use the `FileUrlGenerator` service:

```
$urlEntity = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generate($file->getFileUri())
$url = $urlEntity->toString();

// or

$url = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateString($file->getFileUri())
```