# How to specify the correct private file path in a block

Tags: 8, files

I have a Drupal site at http://example.org/xyz

Per the [instructions here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/file/overview#private-file-system), I have set up a private file directory outside the web root.

So let's say the web root is at /home/public_html/example/xyz
The private directory is at /home/public_html/private

I have that private directory set in the settings.php file and cleared the caches. It shows up correctly here: http://example.org/xyz/admin/config/media/file-system

After clearing the cache, I can indeed confirm there is a valid .htaccess file in /atrium/admin/config/media/file-system

The directory permissions for the private directory are 755.

So now I specify the file location of a link in a block as "/xyz/system/myfile.pdf"

When I click the link, the home page simply reloads (instead of a download window), but the URL now reads:
http://example.org/atrium/system/myfile.pdf

I've tried many other variations, and they all fail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the public folder to provide links in a block? Private folders typically are used for when users upload forms containing sensitive information that only the site owners should see. Either way, have you tried [Private Files Download block](https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission)? This allows you to set permissions by role, which I am assuming is for anonymous users.

Answer (score 0):

drupal will not let you specify a direct link to a private file

If you upload the file using file field (core) then you can use views to display the file in a block using `block display` and use https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission for fine grained permissions on who can download the file

if you want to program this behaviour then you have to look at using `file_create_url` in a custom module

```
$fid = 1; //set fid to your file's fid.
$downloadlink = file_create_url(file_load($fid)->uri);
```

and this link will hide the actual path where you private file is

for more details you can look at

[How can I get the URL to the public files directory?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203509/how-can-i-get-the-url-to-the-public-files-directory/203527)

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/8.2.x