# Get Path from node ID

Tags: theming, 8

I'm using a twig template for a custom block that have images to link to specific nodes. I actually have the node IDs, however generating a relative link doesn't always work. Some pages are using aliases like so
127.0.0.1/web/products and some are using nodes like 127.0.0.1/web/node/19
so using the same relative link doesn't always work. Note that my drupal instance is within a /web/ folder and not at just 127.0.0.1

My twig template looks like this

```
<div class="row columns">
    {% for key, image in imageurl %}
    <div class="large-4 medium-3 column">
        <a href="./node/{{ nid[key] }}">
            <img src="../sites/default/files/{{ image }}"/>
        </a>
        <div>
            {{ block_title[key] }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

When it appears on 127.0.0.1/web/products the link is

```
http://127.0.0.1/web/node/15
```

When it appears on 127.0.0.1/web/node/19 the link is

```
http://127.0.0.1/web/node/node/9
```

The image has the same issue, since 'image' only contains the filename.
Is there a way I can automatically generate a link based on a node ID and a file that I know the path to, to account for URLs that may contain aliases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Drupal 8 classes to generate the link. If you get the nid from an existing node object you can do the following in the .theme-file of your theme:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  $node = Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
  $vars['link'] = $node->toUrl()->setAbsolute();
}
```

In twig you can output:

```
<div class="row columns">
    {% for key, image in imageurl %}
    <div class="large-4 medium-3 column">
        <a href="{{ link }}">
            <img src="../sites/default/files/{{ image }}"/>
        </a>
        <div>
            {{ block_title[key] }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

To generate the URL of your node just knowing the nid (here in variable $nid) you can use the following in your .theme-file:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  $options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
  $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid], $options);
  $vars['link'] = $url->toString();
}
```

Again you can use {{ link }} to output the URL where ever you need in yout twig template.

Comment: I would also advise against writing the image paths like that. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/185572/10729 for information on how to safely get the path to the public files directory.

Comment: I can get the path to show up on a page template when using the reprocess_page hook but for some reason when I use it in the preprocess_block it doesn't appear in the block template. Could that have something to do with the custom block being created within a custom module?

Comment: I ended up getting the path by using your code within the Block plugin file.