# How do I get the path for the private filesystem?

Tags: 8, files

I just trying to get the real path of my private filesystem but I just obtain an empty string if I use:

```
\Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath("private://");
```

There one user in [Get the public path directory](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/185572/28275) that says that this is the correct way, but this is not working for me.

My private filesystem is configured as:

```
$settings['file_private_path'] = '/User/adriancid/private-drupal-folder';
```

[image]

If I use `file_default_scheme()` I see:

> private

Comment: Does it work with `temporary://` or `public://`? Could be that you have not configured the private path in settings.php.

Comment: @4k4 It works for public, and I have configured my private filysystem.

Comment: @4k4 This code: `\Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath("private://");` works for you?

Comment: Yes, it works when a private path is configured and returns FALSE on a site with no path configured. I see in the edit, you have an absolute path outside of the web root, is the path accessible by the web server?

Comment: @4k4 no, is not accesible by the web server.

Comment: It should be writable by the web server, otherwise the status page will report this as error. But for the problem here it doesn't matter, I've tested this, realpath() still returns the (not correct) path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I had a problem with the path, so the correct path is

```
$settings['file_private_path'] = '/Users/adriancid/private-drupal-folder';
```

And I give permissions to write in the folder to the webserver.